# Valor Capturado DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, textbox, datagridview

Estoy intentando mostrar el valor de una consulta en SQL mediante un DataGridView. Para ser más preciso, al seleccionar un ítem del DataGridView me debe mostrar el valor de SQL. Es decir, en el DataGridView yo muestro el ID de los clientes, y al seleccionar un ítem quiero que me muestre el celular en un TextBox. El problema es queno me está mostrando nada.

```
public void llenarId() {//con este método lleno el datagridview
            try {
                string cadena = "cadenaConexion";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadena)) {
                    con.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT id FROM clientes GROUP BY id";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    dtgId.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    con.Close();
                }
            } catch(SqlException ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

private void dtgId_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){//con este trato de capturar el dato y mostrarlo en un textbox
            var row = dtgId.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            var id = row.Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
            try
            {
                string conn = "cadenaConexion";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn)){
                    con.Open();
                    string sql = "SELECT celular FROM clientes WHERE id=@id";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read()){
                        txtNum.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["celular"]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException exc){
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

¿Hay algún error? ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Qué estás usando para mostrar los datos?

Comment: Un DataGridView @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: te manda algun error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usarlo asi:

Usa el evento CellDoubleClick para obtener el ID del datagrid asi:

```
if(e.ColumnIndex == 0)//numero de columna donde esta el ID
        {
string id= dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
try
        {
            string conn = "cadenaConexion";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn)){
                con.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT celular FROM clientes WHERE id=@id";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read()){
                    txtNum.Text = reader["celular"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException exc){
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

}

Comment: Vale, que si me ha funcionado de esta manera. Muchas gracias (estaba dando un solo click)

Comment: pon un punto de interrupcion y debuguea linea por linea para ver donde se queda o si se salta alguna linea.

Comment: ¿Y en caso de querer seleccionar varios items? ¿Cómo debo hacer?

Comment: tienes que hacer una pregunta nueva.